# Implementing Google Sign In without a popup window

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have Sign In With Google in my Angular/FireBase application.

Instead of the popup, I'd really like to move the user defined scope options into the page.

Facebook has options for this I believe but [Google's Sign In docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthsigninoptions) are not clear on if this is possible.

Is this allowed and where can I read about it?

Comment: you can have a look at react-firebaseui: https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web-react. It's easy to configure and has several auth providers

Answer (score 1):

There is "ux_mode: redirect" option (default is "popup") in [gapi SignIn method](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthsigninoptions). It provides sign-in process inside the page and after authentication user is redirected to the "redirect_uri"

For the Firebase auth there is [signInWithRedirect](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#sign-inwith-redirect) method with the same functionality